# URL rewriting/ redirection

Tags: php, node.js, url, real-time, redirect

any ideas on redirecting a web page to another page without altering the url?
I have created this web application using Node.js and php wherein I run the node app in http://localhost:8008 but i want to display the url or when you type the URL to access this page is http://localhost/iochat/.

Comment: You have to configure your application to run on port 80 if you want it to display as `https://localhost` instead of `http://localhost:8080`. Apart from that, maybe look at `history.replaceState()`.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-http-proxy if you are using express, or search by your self

Comment: Thanks it was a great help. I already did what you said